# Most efficient way to get the string with highest priority out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6, comparison

Let's say I have an array as follow:

```
var numArray = [ 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3 ];
```

I could easily get the maximum value out of it by using:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, array);
```

But what if I had an array as follow:

```
var stringArray = [ "Foo", "Very Foo", "Not So Foo", 
                    "Foo", "Very Foo", "Extremely Foo" ];
```

Then what would be the most efficient way to get the maximum value out of it, maximum value being, in order of importance: "Extremely Foo" > "Very Foo" > "Foo" > "Not So Foo"

The first thing that came to mind was iterating through the array with a loop and comparing manually as such:

```
var maxValue = "";
for(var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    if(maxValue != "Extremely Foo") {
        if(maxValue != "Very Foo") {
            if(maxValue != "Foo") {
                maxValue = stringArray[i];
            }
            else if(stringArray[i] != "Not So Foo") {
                maxValue = stringArray[i];
            }
        }
        else if(stringArray[i] == "Extremely Foo") {
            maxValue = stringArray[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    else { break; }
}
```

Then I thought about making an enum to give each different string a value:

```
enum Foos {
    Not So Foo = 0,
    Foo = 1,
    Very Foo = 2,
    Extremely Foo = 3,
}
```

And using the enum value as a comparison method to use the greater than logical operator instead.

My question is: What's the best way to achieve what I am trying to achieve? One of the two ways I mentioned or is there a different way to do it in Javascript that is more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Array#reduce, and on each iteration take string with the highest value in the enum:

```js
var foosEnum = { "Not So Foo": 0, "Foo": 1, "Very Foo": 2, "Extremely Foo": 3 };
var stringArray = [ "Foo", "Very Foo", "Not So Foo", "Foo", "Very Foo", "Extremely Foo" ];
                    
var result = stringArray.reduce(function(c, n) {
  return foosEnum[c] > foosEnum[n] ? c : n;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I love the array.reduce usage here. Very clean and it means I don't have to modify my original array with a sort.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible however to break the reduce execution if we find the highest possible value "Extremely Foo"? Considering finishing the iteration through the array would be pointless.

Comment: You can't break out of Array#reduce, but you can use the old for or while loops to break when something is found. However, if we're talking about short arrays, that you don't iterate all the time, and you don't expect  "Extremely Foo" to appear in a very high frequency, the pointlessness won't be that often.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :)

Comment: In Foo we trust :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array of your priorities in ascending order, then sort your `stringArray` using the order index:

```js
const stringArray = [ "Foo", "Very Foo", "Not So Foo", 
                    "Foo", "Very Foo", "Extremely Foo" ]
const order = ['Not so Foo', 'Foo', 'Very Foo', 'Extremely Foo'];
stringArray.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(b) - order.indexOf(a))
console.log(stringArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had an array of `fooportance`, you could create a `fooness` function that determines the most foo value in the array of foos

```js
function fooness(foo) {
  var fooportance = ["Extremely Foo", "Very Foo", "Foo", "Not So Foo"];
  return fooportance.indexOf(foo);
}

var stringArray = ["Foo", "Very Foo", "Not So Foo", "Foo", "Very Foo", "Extremely Foo"];

stringArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return fooness(a) > fooness(b);
});

var mostFoo = stringArray[0];

console.log(mostFoo)
```

Comment: fooness and fooportance hehe. :p +1 for that, however I think the array.reduce answer better fit what I was looking for.

Comment: @snaplemouton - fair enough, I'd personlly like some reduction with a bit more fooness -> https://jsfiddle.net/rjoxyq2a/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should have an **array of numbers** and simply **convert** the numbers into strings if you need to display them.