# How to sort an array of string per priority?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'd like to ask how could I sort an array of string per priority email domain?

For example, this is my priority list

```
1st: gmail.com
2nd: outlook.com
3rd: yahoo.com
4th: hotmail.com
5th: live.com
6th: Other Domain
```

So, if this is my string

```
const personalEmail = ['email@yahoo.com','email@live.com','email@other.com','email@gmail.com','email@outlook.com']
```

What are ways to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array) also [Most efficient way to get the string with highest priority out of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574811/most-efficient-way-to-get-the-string-with-highest-priority-out-of-an-array) or [Ordering an array of strings according to a specific arrangement of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740589/ordering-an-array-of-strings-according-to-a-specific-arrangement-of-strings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the order of the domains in an array, then in the `sort` callback, subtract the two domain's index in the array to determine precedence.

If one of the indexes is `-1`, sort the other item before the one whose domain wasn't in the array.

```js
const domainPrecedence = ['gmail.com', 'outlook.com', 'yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com', 'live.com']

const personalEmail = ['email@yahoo.com', 'email@live.com', 'email@other.com', 'email@gmail.com', 'email@outlook.com']


const sorted = personalEmail.sort((a, b) => {
  let index1 = domainPrecedence.indexOf(a.split('@')[1])
  let index2 = domainPrecedence.indexOf(b.split('@')[1])
  return index1 == -1 ? 1 : index2 == -1 ? -1 : index1 - index2;
})

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that other.com means it could by any other domain.

```js
const priority = [
  'gmail.com',
  'outlook.com',
  'yahoo.com',
  'hotmail.com',
  'live.com',
];

const personalEmail = [

  'email@yahoo.com',
  'email@live.com',
  'lasvegas@baby.com',
  'email@other.com',
  'email@gmail.com',
  'email@outlook.com',
];

console.log(
  personalEmail.sort((a, b) => {
    const firstIndex = priority.indexOf(a.split('@')[1]);
    const secondIndex = priority.indexOf(b.split('@')[1]);
    return (
      (firstIndex === -1 ? 5 : firstIndex) -
      (secondIndex === -1 ? 5 : secondIndex)
    );
  }),
);
```